# How to make a horizontal FlatList with React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to align those white circles row-wise and I have written the same thing in the code but these circles are getting aligned column-wise, someone can help please.

My `Item` component:

```
const Item = ({ item }) => (
  <View style={styles.citiesContainer}>
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.cities}>{item}</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  citiesContainer: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "nowrap",
    overflow: "hidden",
    height: 120,
    width: "100%",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    alignContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
  cities: {
    fontSize: 10,
    flex: 1,
    color: "black",
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 50,
    backgroundColor: "#f0f0f0",
  },
});
```

Where I am rendering it:

```js
const renderItem = ({ item }) => ( <Item title={item} /> ); 
<FlatList
  data={cities}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  keyExtractor={item => item}      
/>
```

Check the image below to see what I am explaining:

[image]

Comment: What is rendering `Item`?

Comment: @ksav const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <Item title={item} />
    );                                                                                                                       
                   <FlatList
                    data={cities}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={item => item}
                />

Comment: This is a CSS issue, `display: flex` should be set in the `Items` container, not the item itself. Quick guide - notice how all `display: flex` have a container indicator : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: So you want `FlatList` to render horizontally? `<FlatList horizontal={true} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have items on a row, all you need is to add `horizontal={true}` on  `FlatList`. Like so:

```js
 <FlatList
   data={cities} 
   renderItem={renderItem}
   keyExtractor={item => item.id} 
   horizontal={true} 
 />
```

Since you have `const renderItem = ({ item }) => (<Item title={item} />)`, in `Item` you should be getting `title` as part of `props`. And finally change `styles` object as below:

```
const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.city}>
    <Text>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  city: {
    fontSize: 10,
    color: "black",
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 50,
    backgroundColor: "#f0f0f0",
  },
});
```

Comment: you are right as of now, but a new problem arises, now those circles are gone i mean are not visible

Comment: Can you modify your post and add where you are using the FlatList ?

Comment: should I write complete code?

Comment: Yeah copy past the FlatList part along with what you have already pasted.

Comment: Yes, it was also a mistake, so I copied and pasted your updated answer, but still those circles are not visible

Comment: Hope we will get trough this. I edited my answer. Change the Item component with mine, the new one.